# Why calling an async function whose defination is given in another program returns null or Future<type> instance for the first time as output?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hello Im very to the flutter framework, so please let me know if im going wrong anywhere and the appropriate way of doing the things.

[this is a drawerPage.dar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpclD.png)

In this file im trying to call a function getData for retrieving the data from firebase,this fucntion is in Database.dart file.

[Database.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhmxc.png)

In the Database.dart file i wrote the getData function inside which im retrieving a particular record from the firebase and storing in a global variable. And then im trying to print the global variable in the drawerPage.dart file.But here when ever i run the program, for the first time the variable is having a null value and upon hot reload the actual value is getting stored in the variable.Please let me know how can i get rid of this problem.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmfgc.png)

[drawerPageOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVdo2.png)

drawerPage.dart

```
import 'package:attendee/constants.dart';
import 'package:attendee/models/userdeails.dart';
import 'package:attendee/pages/profile.dart';
import 'package:attendee/services/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:attendee/services/database.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:attendee/pages/userdetails.dart';

class StudentDashboard extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _StudentDashboardState createState() => _StudentDashboardState();
}

class _StudentDashboardState extends State<StudentDashboard> {
  userdetails userdetail;

   final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final AuthenticationService _auth = AuthenticationService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DatabaseService().getData('email');
    final drawerHeader = UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      accountName: Text(userName),
      accountEmail: Text('${result}'),
      currentAccountPicture
          : CircleAvatar(
        child: FlutterLogo(size: 42.0),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
    final drawerItems = ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        drawerHeader,
        ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.perm_identity_outlined),
              Text(' Profile'),
            ],
          ),
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Profile())),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('To page 2'),
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(_NewPage(2)),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title:Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.exit_to_app_rounded),
              Text(' Logout'),
            ],
          ),
          onTap: () async {
            await _auth.signOut();
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homepage');
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
    return StreamProvider<List<userdetails>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().students,
      initialData: [],
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
              title: Text('Student Welcome'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton.icon(
                     onPressed: () async {
                      await _auth.signOut();
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homepage');
                     
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    label: Text('Logout'))
              ],
            ),
            body:
               UserDetails(),
      

            drawer: GestureDetector(
              onTap: display,
              child: Drawer(
                child: drawerItems,
              ),
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

   display() async{
     await DatabaseService().getData('email');
  }
}

// <Null> means this route returns nothing.
class _NewPage extends MaterialPageRoute<Null> {
  _NewPage(int id)
      : super(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page $id'),
        elevation: 1.0,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Page $id'),
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

database.dart

```
import 'package:attendee/models/userdeails.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';

import '../constants.dart';

class DatabaseService{

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

//collection reference
final CollectionReference user_details=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');`
final CollectionReference tutor_details` `=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tutors");`


Future updateStudentData(String fullname,String mobilenumber,String `email,String rollno,String tutorid,String role) async {`
return await user_details.doc(uid).set({
  'fullname' : fullname,
  'mobilenumber': mobilenumber,
  'email' : email,
  'rollno': rollno,
  'tutorid': tutorid,
  'role' : role,//FMERT series
});
  }

Future updateTutorData(String fullname,String mobilenumber,String `email,String rollno,String tutorid,String role) async {`
    return await tutor_details.doc(uid).set({
      'fullname' : fullname,
      'mobilenumber': mobilenumber,
      'email' : email,
      'rollno': rollno,
      'tutorid': tutorid,
      'role' : role,//FMERT series
    });
  }
  //studentDetails from snapshot
  List<userdetails> _studentDetailsFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return userdetails(
        fullname: doc.data()['fullname'] ?? '',
        mobilenumber: doc.data()['mobilenumber'] ?? '',
        email: doc.data()['email'] ?? '',
        rollno: doc.data()['rollno'] ?? '',
        tutorid: doc.data()['tutorid'] ?? '',
        //role: doc.data()['role'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  //get students stream
  Stream<List<userdetails>> get students {
    return user_details.snapshots()
        .map(_studentDetailsFromSnapshot);
  }

  //tutorsDetails from snapshot
  List<userdetails> _tutorDetailsFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return userdetails(
        fullname: doc.data()['fullname'] ?? '',
        mobilenumber: doc.data()['mobilenumber'] ?? '',
        email: doc.data()['email'] ?? '',
        rollno: doc.data()['rollno'] ?? '',
        tutorid: doc.data()['tutorid'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  //get tutors stream
  Stream<List<userdetails>> get tutors {
    return user_details.snapshots()
        .map(_studentDetailsFromSnapshot);
  }

  void display() {
    tutor_details.get().then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
        print(result.data());
      });
    });
  }

   getData (String string) async{
    String userId = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    final document = isTutor ? `FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('tutors/$userId') :`
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/$userId'); 
    document.get().then((DocumentSnapshot) async {
      if(string =='role') {
        checkRole = DocumentSnapshot.data()[string].toString();
        print('$checkRole inside getData Function');
        //return checkRole;
        print(checkRole);
      }
      else {
        print(result);
        result = await DocumentSnapshot.data()[string].toString();
        print('${DocumentSnapshot.data()[string].toString()} in the `database else block');`
        //return result;
      }
    //print(document("name"));
    });
  }
  }
```

After changes
[terminaloutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGO6F.png)
[draweroutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdAp9.png)

Comment: is it not working if you uncomment `return result` ?

Comment: instead of sharing screenshot please share the code

Comment: I see lots and lots of squiggly lines. Please remove all your warnings first, your compiler is telling you where you are wrong and you ignore it.

Comment: @UjjwalRaijada i have added the code. Please check it out and help me with this.

Comment: @orotype No it is not working

Comment: Yes @nvoigt i actually need guidance im a complete beginner in this.

Answer (score 0):

""when ever i run the program, for the first time the variable is having a null value and upon hot reload the actual value is getting stored in the variable""

When we try to get data from http / https request, it takes some time. Meanwhile the page gets loaded and you get null values.

You can use `Provider` package to resolve this issue, or try the below code. Please add the below code in your drawerPage.dart.

What I have done below is made getData() return type. Only on receiving a value from this function, _loadOnce will change to false & final screen will be shown.

Database.dart

```
Future<bool> getData (String string) async{
    String userId = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    final document = isTutor ? `FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('tutors/$userId') :`
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/$userId'); 
    document.get().then((DocumentSnapshot) async {
      if(string =='role') {
        checkRole = DocumentSnapshot.data()[string].toString();
        print('$checkRole inside getData Function');
        //return checkRole;
        print(checkRole);
        return true;
      }
      else {
        print(result);
        result = await DocumentSnapshot.data()[string].toString();
        print('${DocumentSnapshot.data()[string].toString()} in the `database else block');`
        //return result;
        return false;
      }
    //print(document("name"));
    });
  }
  }
```

```
/// create a new variable.
bool _loadOnce = true;
```

```
/// shift your code `DatabaseService().getData('email');`
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if(_loadOnce == true) {
      DatabaseService().getData('email').then((value) { 
        if(value == true){
          setState(() {
            _loadOnce = false;
          });
        } else {
         /// you can write your code here
          setState(() {
            _loadOnce = false;
          });
        }
      )}
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Below code will show a spinner till the time all the code gets executed and values are retreived.

```
/// in your main page under Scaffold
body: _loadOnce == true
  ? Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    ),
  )
  : UserDetails(),
```

Comment: This also didnt worked. Is there any means through which i can show you the live demonstration like discord or anything?

Comment: Sorry to know that. I have made some changes. PLease try this. It should work.

Comment: Now it is showing some different thing at the start 
"Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' "

Comment: The output/error message itself is Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' instead of printing email id. I have also updated the output images please check. And please if theres any mean where i can actually show you the exact working( like discord or something else) please let me know.